# Sum the value of the second character in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I sum the value of the second character of each cell?

```
---------------------
| Block A | Block B |
---------------------
| A1221   | R7798   |
| E2154   | E4445   |
| E5442   | G4486   |
| V2211   | C5565   |
| B9984   | E4569   |
---↑---------↑------
   sum       sum
```

So, for example, I would like to output `19` for "Block A" and `24` for "Block B"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this For  Block A just create a new column C and on the same row as A1221  put this formula

```
=VALUE(MID(B2,2,1))
```

That will extract just the first number. Copy and page this formular for all the cells in column c,  Then you can so a simple sum of column C

See demo here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Au2BC1Mvfu_adGpVNkY0WVkweXB5SnpWZHpNc3Uycmc

Answer (score 2):

To do it in one go without resorting to a help column (and assuming Block A is in column A), you can try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A5; 2; 1))
```